# Using datatool on files with lines breaks

Tags: datatool

I have a generated CSV file which has line breaks (newline characters) in values. They are properly quoted. When reading this data with `DTLloadrawdb` LaTeX complains as those line breaks still breaks the reading. The problem is that I do not know how could I fix this with `\DTLrawmap` (to change newlines into `\DTLpar`). Or is there some other way to fix it? I would like to not have to preprocess CSV files outside of LaTeX.

Answer (score 5):

The `datatool` documentation seems pretty clear that "each row of a data in an external file must not have a line break" (p.36). The `pgfplotstable` package can handle linebreaks in CSV files, but only if all cells are enclosed in braces.

Comment: It may be possible to solve Mitar's problem by changing the value of \endlinechar, and making the corresponding character active, `\let` (or `\def` ed) to `\DTLpar`. I don't know the datatool package, though.